# Prove directly that $a_n = 2^n / n!$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$a_n = 2^n/n!$ Hint: look at the ratio of successive terms

I understand that I have to show that for sufficiently large n, $|2^n/n!| < \epsilon$. However, I do not know how to rewrite the inequality in terms of $n$. I do not get how the hint can assist me in directly proving this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{2^n}{n!}=\frac{2^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\cdot\frac{2}{n}.$ Can you go from here?

Comment: I can see how one repeats this pattern $n$ times, but I do not understand how to simplify from there.

Comment: For sufficiently large $n,$ $\frac2n<1.$ What does this say about the sequence?

Comment: That it converges to 1/2. Is this intuition correct? I was under the impression that this sequence converged to 0.

Comment: no... if a number keeps getting multiplied by a number less than $1,$ what happens?

Comment: Oh, I see. It approaches 0. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $0\leq a_n \leq 2$ for every $n\geq0$.
The hint asks you to look at $b_n=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$.
I then invite you to answer if $b_n$ is less than, greater than or equal to $1$.
Can you finish from here?

Remember that a bounded and monotonic sequence is convergent (see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem)).

Comment: I am getting that $b_n = 2/(n+1)$ which would mean that for sufficiently large n, it is 0. Is this correct? If so, how do I end up using inequalities to directly prove this?

Comment: Ok, so $b_n=2/(n+1)$. Thus, $b_n<1$ for $n>1$, that is, $a_{n+1}<a_n$ for $n>1$. Voilà, $(a_n)_{n>1}$ is decreasing (and bounded below by $0$).

Comment: Is that enough evidence to prove directly? I am new to the subject of Real Analysis

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I've said in my answer. I've added a link for reference, hope it helps.

Comment: Great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As given in the hint:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{2^n}{n!}} = \frac{2}{n+1} < \frac{1}{2} \mbox{ for } n > 3$$
It follows with $a_0 = \frac{2^0}{0!}=1$ for $n>5$
$$0 < a_n = \frac{a_n}{a_0}= \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}\cdot\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}} \cdots \frac{a_2}{a_1}\cdot \frac{a_1}{a_0}< \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-5}\frac{a_4}{a_0}\stackrel{n\rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$

Answer (score 0):

When $b_n=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\rho\lt1$ we get convergence by *comparison* with the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\rho^n$, if memory serves...

We have that, since $b_n=\frac2{n+1}$.

**Edit:**  Now I see that you didn't mean the series,  but rather the sequence.   The sledgehammer would be that since the series converges,  the sequence goes to zero.

To prove it "directly":

Since $a_n\lt a_1\cdot\rho^n$, with $\rho\lt1$, we've got it (let $n\to\infty$).

Comment: So can I use the ratio of successive terms $b_n$ in place of $a_n$?

Comment: For sufficiently large n, $|2/(n+1)| < \epsilon$

Comment: Yes.  Try it.  You can replace $a_n$ with $\rho^n\cdot a_1$, say.  Your series should be less than $a_1\cdot\sum\rho^n$...

Comment: Oops.  I assumed you had a _series_...

Comment: Would |2/(n+1)|<ϵ  still work? If this is a legal step, I can solve from here.

Comment: The ratio test is really for series.  Though if the series converges (and it does),  the $a_n$'s go to zero.  Not sure what you mean by a legal step here... but I suspect not.

Answer (score 0):

See, for $n\ge 6$ we have, $(n-1)!>2^n$

So, $0<\frac{2^n}{n!}<\frac{1}{n}$ for $n\ge 6$

Now, applying Sandwich theorem, we get

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^n}{n!}=0$

Comment: This is how I found the answer, but unfortunately, it does not satisfy my professor's "direct proof" criteria. Thank you, though! :)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for $n>3$ we have $$0<a_{n+1}=\dfrac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=\dfrac{2}{n+1}a_n<\dfrac{1}{2}a_n$$using Squeeze theorem we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$$